# How to send Twitter updates from C#

Tags: c#, twitter

how do I send Twitter updates in C# but without the need of OAuth?

The reason is, is because I heard that Twitter limits how many Tweets one can send, and I am planning to send a lot.

Comment: how many tweets are you looking to send? What is the tweet limit set by Twitter?

Comment: `I heard that Twitter limits how many Tweets one can send` This is the limit. If you need more, here is the support http://support.twitter.com/

Comment: I might send around 20 an hour thats why. Do oy uknow of any good DLLs?

Comment: I also dont want to use OAuth because it only tweets to one account, and I want my users to tweet as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The officially supported means of sending a tweet via a third party application is by using the [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) twitter provides. This does require clients to use OAuth to authenticate.

If you don't want to deal with the API directly you might consider using a library which wraps the official API. I can't personally recommend any particular library as I have not used a Twitter library in a long while, however Twitter does provide a list of [API implementations](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#dotnet) which may interest you.

It is possible that one could use the WebBrowser control to interface with twitter by website form fields with values passed to your application through your application's user interface.

Doing this is not advised for the following reasons:

1. It's officially unsupported and against Twitter's [terms of use](https://twitter.com/tos). This method depends on your application parsing the twitter user interface in order to find and populate form feilds. The names of these feilds may change at any tine without notice.
2. It will not circumvent the rate limiting. Twitter's rate limiting is enforced at the server side and the web interface is not likely to be immune to this rate limiting.

Comment: When you enter your OAUTH credentials, does it mean that you can only send updates to your twitter not to others?

Comment: The authentication tells twitter who is logged in, it controls who tweets appear to be from. You should be able to send tweets to anyone that the logged in account can send tweets to